# Is $C(\Bbb R)$ homeomorphic to $C([a,b])$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity

Let $C(\Bbb R)$ be the space of all continuous self-maps of $\Bbb R$ in the compact convergence topology (which is same as compact-open topology) and $C([a,b])$ be the space of all continuous self-maps of [a,b] in the uniform topology. Is $C(\Bbb R)$ homeomorphic to $C([a,b])$?

Comment: I´m not sure about the full spaces of continuous functions right now, but $\mathrm{Homeo}([0,1])$ and $\mathrm{Homeo}(\Bbb R)$ are isomorphic when both have the compact-open topology, so I expect the same to hold for the full groups

Comment: Using the post notation, in $C[a,b]$ I see two *special* points: constants $a,b$. Is there an homeo of $C[a,b]$ sending those constants elsewhere? (not switching them)

Answer (score 4):

Both are separable completely metrisable locally convex linear spaces, so yes, by "Anderson's theorem". See section 3 in [this survey](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.vanmill/papers/papers2002/dijkstra.pdf) where the result is attributed to Dobrowolski and Toruńczyk. I've seen both attributions used. **Added:** not valid for self-maps of $[a,b]$ as this is not a linear space. I assumed the standard notion of real-valued maps instead. But in Bessaga and Pelzcynski, *Topics in Infinite-dimensional topology*, Thm 6.2 we find that a closed convex body (so it has non-empty interior) in an infinite-dimensional Fréchet space is homeomorphic to the whole space (and to $\ell^2$ and $\Bbb R^{\omega}$ etc.). And $C([a,b])$ is surely that. So it does indeed hold, by such general facts: there is very little topological variety in such function spaces (when Polish).

Comment: C([a,b]) is not a linear space as it is not closed under addition. Note that here C([a,b]) denote space of all self-maps of [a,b].

Comment: @ChaithanyaGk I took it for the standard notation for real-valued maps on $[a,b]$ and for this the result holds.

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted the answer for space of self-maps of [a,b].

Comment: @ChaithanyaGk It's sort of like the unit ball in $C([a,b], \Bbb R)$, so maybe it will still be homeomorphic. Just with an extra argument.

Comment: Can you please give little more detail? I don't think it is very obvious that C([a,b]) is homeomorphic to C([a,b],R).

Comment: @ChaithanyaGk Well, $C([a,b]) \simeq C([a,b], [-1,1])$ which is just the unit ball in $C([a,b], \Bbb R)$

Comment: OK, How did you conclude that C([a,b],[-1,1]) is homeomorphic to C([a,b],R)? Are you using any known result?

Comment: @ChaithanyaGk All normed topological vector spaces are homeomorphic to their (open) unit ball

Comment: but the ball here is not the open ball, is the closed one

Comment: I think C([a,b],[-1,1]) is closed in C([a,b],R) but not open.

Comment: @ChaithanyaGk They're still homeomorphic, see Bessaga and Pelczynski (topics in infinite-dimensional topology, chapter 6). In such infinite dimensional spaces closed unit balls and the open ones are homeomorphic. But it's not easy..

Comment: Oh OK. I will check. Thank you.

Comment: @ChaithanyaGk you will rarely find explicit homeomorphisms there. But its a classic book for these topics.

Comment: Are you citing Theorem 6.2 in that reference?

Comment: Maybe you should add that a "convex body" means "a convex subset with nonempty interior." Incidentally, one should also assume $a<b$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, of course I consider a<b.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  Why C(R,R) in the compact open topology is locally convex? Does it follow from a well-known result?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I know that the metric $D(f,g)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\frac{\rho_k(f,g)}{1+\rho_k(f,g)}$ with \rho_k as the uniform metric on E_k, where R is the countable union of compact sets E_k, induces the compact open topology on C(R,R). How it is normable?

Comment: @ChaithanyaGk The $\rho_k$ are already a family of seminorms for $C(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)$ from which local convexity follows as well; normable might be overstating it. It has a countable family of seminorms, which is almost as good.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I understood the reasoning now. Thank you.